# Wait for ajax request to complete - selenium webdriver

Tags: ajax, selenium-webdriver

I am stuck at point where i want my script to wait until ajax request is completed.

I tried :
1. Running application in slow network mode, click create button and checked JQuery.active returns 1. There is only ajax call happening.

Problem is whole page is not refreshed.Its just some data on page that is updated everytime.

I used explicit wait to wait until loader/progress bar disappears but i am asked to specifically wait for ajax to complete as UI might change soon.

I tried implementing:

```
public boolean waitForJSandJQueryToLoad() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    // wait for jQuery to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          return ((Long)((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          // no jQuery present
          return true;
        }
      }
    };

    // wait for Javascript to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return ((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("return document.readyState")
        .toString().equals("complete");
      }
    };

  return wait.until(jQueryLoad) && wait.until(jsLoad);
}
```

But its not working. My test are failing because assertions are called before ajax is completed and data is updated.

Can someone give me working solution to :
1. Check AJAX is running.
2. Wait until ajax is completed.
3. Wait until data is updated/refreshed, not whole page.

Thanks !!

Comment: The _usecase_ which you spoke about e.g. _Check AJAX is running_, _Wait until ajax is completed_ and _Wait until data is updated/refreshed, not whole page_ are all trivial. Your actual _usecase_ should be definite and must be related to interaction with _WebElements_ on the page. Can you update the question with your exact _usecase_, relevant _HTML_ and _code trials_?

Comment: Here is exact usecase :

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code I use to wait for Ajax to finish:

```
public static void waitForAjaxToFinish() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        public Boolean apply(WebDriver wdriver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0").equals(true);
        }

    });
}
```

and the code I use to wait until JQuery is active:

```
public static void waitForJQueryToBeActive() {
    Boolean isJqueryUsed = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return (typeof(jQuery) != 'undefined')");
    if (isJqueryUsed) {
        while (true) {
            // JavaScript test to verify jQuery is active or not
            Boolean ajaxIsComplete = (Boolean) (((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                    .executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
            if (ajaxIsComplete)
                break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you elaborate why do we need to wait for jquery to be active?

Comment: This comment was six years ago, so I can't remember anymore.  I was working as an automation engineer but I retired a little over a year after that.  I think it was just a way to ensure that JQuery was available and not in use by another thread/process, but again, I don't remember.

Comment: fair enough. i went with your code, and made my own custom selenium click with readyState and ajax wait. Seems to work fine. Cheers.