# Do we have any generic function to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageload, dom-events

I am trying to check if web page is loaded completed or not (i.e. checking that all the control is loaded) in selenium.

I tried below code:

```
new WebDriverWait(firefoxDriver, pageLoadTimeout).until(
          webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

but even if page is loading above code does not wait.

I know that I can check for particular element to check if its visible/clickable etc but I am looking for some generic solution

Comment: You can check the page of URL to see whether page is loaded or not?

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned if there is any generic function to check if the page has completely loaded through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) the answer is **No**.

First let us have a look at your code trial which is as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(firefoxDriver, pageLoadTimeout).until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

The parameter `pageLoadTimeout` in the above line of code doesn't really reseambles to actual [pageLoadTimeout()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Here you can find a detailed discussion of [pageLoadTimeout in Selenium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working)

---

Now as your *usecase* relates to page being completely loaded you can use the [pageLoadStrategy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322165/dont-wait-for-a-page-to-load-using-selenium-in-python/46339092#46339092) set to **`normal`** [ the supported values being *none*, *eager* or *normal* ] using either through an instance of **DesiredCapabilities** Class or **ChromeOptions** Class as follows :

- Using *DesiredCapabilities* Class :

  ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

   public class myDemo 
   {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
          dcap.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "normal");
          FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
          opt.merge(dcap);
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Using *ChromeOptions* Class :

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy;

  public class myDemo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
          opt.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Page load strategy for Chrome driver (Updated till Selenium v3.12.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver-updated-till-selenium-v3-12-0/43737358#43737358)

---

Now setting *PageLoadStrategy* to **NORMAL** and your code trial both ensures that the *Browser Client* have (i.e. the *Web Browser*) have attained `'document.readyState'` equal to `"complete"`. Once this condition is fulfilled Selenium performs the next line of code.

You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium IE WebDriver only works while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709234/selenium-ie-webdriver-only-works-while-debugging/47710701#47710701)

But the *Browser Client* attaining `'document.readyState'` equal to `"complete"` still doesn't guarantees that all the *JavaScript* and *Ajax Calls* have completed.

---

To wait for the all the *JavaScript* and *Ajax Calls* to complete you can write a function as follows :

```
public void WaitForAjax2Complete() throws InterruptedException
{
    while (true)
    {
        if ((Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0")){
            break;
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Wait for ajax request to complete - selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230269/wait-for-ajax-request-to-complete-selenium-webdriver)

---

Now, the above two approaches through **PageLoadStrategy** and `"return jQuery.active == 0"` looks to be waiting for indefinite events. So for a definite wait you can induce [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) set to [titleContains()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#titleContains-java.lang.String-) method which will ensure that the *Page Title* (i.e. the *Web Page*) is visible and assume the all the elements are also visible as follows :

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("partial_title_of_application_under_test"));
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

---

Now, at times it is possible though the *Page Title* will match your *Application Title* still the desired element you want to interact haven't completed loading. So a more granular approach would be to induce [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) set to [visibilityOfElementLocated()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method which will make your program wait for the desired *element to be visible* as follows :

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
WebElement ele = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_of_the_desired_element")));
System.out.println(ele.getText());
driver.quit();
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium IE WebDriver only works while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709234/selenium-ie-webdriver-only-works-while-debugging/47710701#47710701)
- [Selenium how to manage wait for page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057676/selenium-how-to-manage-wait-for-page-load/60060481#60060481)

Answer (score 0):

I use selenium too and I had the same problem, to fix that I just wait also for the jQuery to load.

So if you have the same issue try this also

```
((Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
```

You can wrap both function in a method and check until both page and jQuery is loaded

Comment: You are making an assumption that the website being driven by Selenium uses JQuery...

Answer (score 0):

Implement this, Its working for many of us including me. It includes Web Page wait on JavaScript, Angular, JQuery if its there.

If your Application is containing Javascript & JQuery you can write code for only those,

By define it in single method and you can Call it anywhere:

```
          // Wait for jQuery to load
          {             
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = driver -> ((Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);

            boolean jqueryReady = (Boolean) js.executeScript("return jQuery.active==0");

            if (!jqueryReady) {
                // System.out.println("JQuery is NOT Ready!");
                wait.until(jQueryLoad);
            }
            wait.until(jQueryLoad);
          }

          // Wait for ANGULAR to load
          {               
            String angularReadyScript = "return angular.element(document).injector().get('$http').pendingRequests.length === 0";

            ExpectedCondition<Boolean> angularLoad = driver -> Boolean.valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(angularReadyScript).toString());

            boolean angularReady = Boolean.valueOf(js.executeScript(angularReadyScript).toString());

            if (!angularReady) {
                // System.out.println("ANGULAR is NOT Ready!");
                wait.until(angularLoad);
            }
          }

          // Wait for Javascript to load    
          {             
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = driver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString()
                    .equals("complete");

            boolean jsReady = (Boolean) js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");

            // Wait Javascript until it is Ready!
            if (!jsReady) {
                // System.out.println("JS in NOT Ready!");
                wait.until(jsLoad);
            }
          }
```

[Click here for Reference Link](https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/)

Let me know if you stuck anywhere by implementing.

It overcomes the use of Thread or Explicit Wait.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19722427)

Comment: @Zabuza : Code Added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void waitForPageToLoad(long timeOutInSeconds) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
    try {
        System.out.println("Waiting for page to load...");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), timeOutInSeconds);
        wait.until(expectation);
    } catch (Throwable error) {
        System.out.println(
                "Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete after " + timeOutInSeconds + " seconds");
    }
}
```

Try this method

Answer (score 0):

This works for me well with dynamically rendered websites:

1. Wait for complete page to load

```html
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50); 
wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd -> ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

2. Make another implicit wait with a dummy condition which would always fail

```html
  try {          
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + "This text will always fail :)" + "')]"))); // condition you are certain won't be true 
  } 
  catch (TimeoutException te) {
  }
```

3. Finally, instead of getting the html source - which would in most of one page applications would give you a different result , pull the outerhtml of the first html tag

```html
String script = "return document.getElementsByTagName(\"html\")[0].outerHTML;"; 
content = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to do it. When you first request the state via javascript, it tells you that the page is `complete`, but after that it enters the state `loading`. The first `complete` state was the initial page!

So my proposal is to check for a `complete` state after a `loading` state. Check this code in PHP, easily translatable to another language.

```php
        $prevStatus  = '';
        $checkStatus = function ($driver) use (&$prevStatus){

          $status = $driver->executeScript("return document.readyState"); 

          if ($prevStatus=='' && $status=='loading'){
            //save the previous status and continue waiting
            $prevStatus = $status; 
            return false;
          }

          if ($prevStatus=='loading' && $status=='complete'){
            //loading -> complete, stop waiting, it is finish!
            return true;
          }
          //continue waiting 
          return false;

        };
        $this->driver->wait(20, 150)->until($checkStatus);
```

Checking for a element to be present also works well, but you need to make sure that this element is only present in the destination page.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work (please excuse the python in a java answer):

```
idle = driver.execute_async_script("""
  window.requestIdleCallback(() => {
    arguments[0](true)
  })
""")
```

This should block until the event loop is idle which means all assets should be loaded.