# How to find an element dynamically loaded by jQuery in page through Selenium, WebDriver and Python

Tags: python, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm having a problem getting an item within a page, this item is loaded after loading the page via **ajax** or **iframe**, is there any way to create a condition for the script to wait until the item appear?

To exemplify my problem I did the following test:

**Python:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://localhost/test_time.php")
delay = 10 # seconds
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'id_2'))) 
    print ("Elememento encontrado")
except TimeoutException:
    print ('Nao foi dessa vez :(')
    pass
```

I search for **id_2** which is displayed 5 seconds after completion of loading the page by JavaScript

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Teste Python</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function sleep(milliseconds) {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
                if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                break;
                }
            }
        }
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            console.log('js start');     
            sleep(5000);
            jQuery('<div> DIV 2 </div>', {id: 'id_2', }).appendTo('#content');                      
            console.log('js Done');                 
        });
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div>Main page</div>
    <div id='content'>
        <div id="id_1">DIV 1</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the HTML I have 2 **div** if you do the search for **div id_1** it finds no problem, but the **div id_2** which is displayed 5 seconds after page loading is not found by selenium even though I determine the wait time of 10 seconds.

I would like a light to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Why don't you manually wait for some time to locate the HTML of the element with  `div id_2`?

Comment: There is no `div id_2` in your HTML, are you sure, that element appears after 5 seconds?

Comment: @DebanjanB Because the page does not have a specific time to load.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov See javascript, has a sleep() then create a div with Jquery

Comment: @Bulfaitelo I see the script, but I'm not sure, that the script does, what you want. That's why I am asking if the `div id_2` actually appears

Comment: You check for jQuery.active status in chrome console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have provided the associated `function` within the `<script>` invokes:

```
jQuery('<div> DIV 2 </div>', {id: 'id_2', }).appendTo('#content');
```

So, when the webpage will finish loading completely an element will be present within the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) as:

```
('<div> DIV 2 </div>', {id: 'id_2', })
```

Here you can find a discussion on [Do we have any generic funtion to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-funtion-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleniu/50329056#50329056)

Finally, you can wait for either of the following state of the element inducing *WebDriverWait* as follows:

- [**`presence_of_element_located(locator)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located):

  ```
  myElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#id_2")))
  ```
- [**`visibility_of_element_located(locator)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located)

  ```
  myElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#id_2")))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'id_2')))
```

try this:

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='content']/div[2]")))
```