# Is it necessary to set waiting time while working with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception

Some said that it is necessary to set waiting time, otherwise it may cause `NoSuchElementException` error because the page didn't finish loading.

However, I tried the following code (without any waiting lines) with a low-speed network (I limited the speed), and the login process still ran smoothly (it kept loading at first, and when I canceled the limit, the loading finished immediately and things went on...).

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json

# Get user info
with open('wjxlogin.json', encoding='utf-8') as fp_login:
    login = json.load(fp_login)
username = login['username']
password = login['password']

# First login
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.wjx.cn/login.aspx')
browser.find_element_by_id('UserName').send_keys(username)
browser.find_element_by_id('Password').send_keys(password)
browser.find_element_by_id('RememberMe').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('LoginButton').click()
```

So, I wonder if there's an automatic waiting mode in current Selenium, which does not allow executing the next line until the last process is finished?
And is it still necessary to set a waiting time (in my code for example)?

Comment: when content is loaded dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **default** timeout in `Selenium` is set to  **0**. What this means is that `Selenium` will throw `NoSuchElementExpception` after the page finishes loading and the particular element is not present in the **DOM**. The default **page** load timeout is pretty high (I think its 600 seconds) - this is why what you have tried did not impact the test execution while network was bad.

However - changing the page load timeout will not result in `NoSuchElementException` instead a different exception will be thrown. If you want to experiment with the settings:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(3)
```

Will probably get you some failures with limited speed network.

When it comes to the waiting - as you saw yourself you did not need it. It is required only in some specific scenarios - i.e. dynamic content gets updated, user interaction loads some elements, etc.

Comment: also worth noting that some dynamic content will update location bar with a bookmark which fires onload.  Sites that use this method may not require a webdriverwait.   (It's a technique that may be outdated, but allowed for bookmarking and proper forward back button functionality.)   The hashchange events fire dynamic loads.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** as per the best practices, you need to set a waiting time i.e. a *waiter* in the form of [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in conjunction with either of the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) when using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491).

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Do we have any generic funtion to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-funtion-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleniu/50329056#50329056)
- [How to sleep webdriver in python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)

---

### This usecase

As per your usecase to login within the [website](https://www.wjx.cn/login.aspx) using a valid set of credentials you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.wjx.cn/login.aspx")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.validate-input.user-name#UserName"))).send_keys("TheCoolestStacker")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#Password[name='Password']").send_keys("TheCoolestStacker")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#RememberMe[name='RememberMe']").click()
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.submitbutton#LoginButton").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: login_wait]

---

### NoSuchElementException

You can find a couple of detailed discussion on *NoSuchElementException* in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)

Comment: Thanks! And do you know why the error didn't happen in my situation? It seems that the "find_element..." line won't execute until the loading is successful or reaches an error page. That's why I'm doubting the necessity of adding "waiting".

Comment: @TheCoolestStacker `loading is successful` term is pretty much subjective from _Selenium's_ perspective. **`find_element_by_*`** in conjunction with `Implicitly Wait` won't be that effective in the bigger picture when you will start interacting with dynamic elements. Hence a better approach would be _WebDriverWait_ which I have spoke about in my answer.

Comment: if there is no additional requests sent after initial pageload, then you wouldn't need to wait.  so it's not always needed