# Unable to run selenium testcases from azure pipeline?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, selenium-ide

I have recorded a few test cases using selenium IDE.I have exported these testcase in the c#(nunit) language.Since the testcases has to be compiled into a .dll file , i created a library project using visual studio community and pasted my testcases into that project.Then i build this project for generating all the necessary .dll files needed to run the testcase from azure.After this i pushed the entire library project folder into azure repos(along with the DLL files).Unfortunately when i run my pipeline, it keeps failing at the task "VsTest - testAssemblies".

Error message from azure logs-

```
Running all tests in d:\a\1\s\chrometest\chrometest\bin\Debug\chrometest.dll
   NUnit3TestExecutor converted 1 of 1 NUnit test cases
  X createnewfolderonly [18s 200ms]
  Error Message:
   OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".butt > span"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
  Stack Trace:
     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(String cssSelector)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<CssSelector>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at DefaultSuiteTest.createnewfolderonly() in C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\chrometest\chrometest\chrometestpage.cs:line 33
```

> Note: I am able to run the dll directly through vstest.console.exe on my local machine using the  command promp without any issue and i dont get any of these errors.I am also able to see the automation happening after this.Why can't i do the same from the azure pipelines?Plz help

Comment: Hi did you check out the workaround mentioned below, how did it go?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes running UI tests locally is faster than on server, and the desired element is not complete loaded when the method get called. Thus you see above error `Unable to locate element...`.

You can try checking option `Test mix contains UI tests` for VsTest task. Or set to rerun the failed tests for a couple of times.

[image]

You can also try using `WebDriverWait for the ElementExists()` in your test code to make sure the element is visible. Please check about [this thread to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-function-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleni/50329056#50329056) for more information.

Hope above helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your locator is not able to find the element for which it is looking for. That’s probably because the website is loading slowly. You can put a wait before every line in your script or you might have given the wrong location.

For example:

```
 Thread.Sleep(3000);  //3 seconds wait
 driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));   // finding element by name
```